# iOS Custom Keyboard Extension Autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm developing a custom keyboard and i want to use only a UICollectionView as content. The CollectionView should fill (center x and y, width and height available space) of the keyboardview.

My problem is that if i rotate the device the collection view won't be resized.

I tried layout constraints, resizing the view on viewWillTransitionToSize but it does not work. Can anyone give me a hint or show me a way to get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autolayout should set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `NO` before adding Constraint. The code below can make a `UICollectionView` autolayout with equal edges.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    UICollectionView *collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero collectionViewLayout:layout];
    collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.view addSubview:collectionView];

    //Adding layout constraint
    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:collectionView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:collectionView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:collectionView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:collectionView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
}
```

In addition, I recommend you to use [Masonry](https://github.com/SnapKit/Masonry) to build autolayout. In your case, you just need to run the code below to make constraints.

```
[collectionView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.edges.equalTo(self.view);
}];
```

By the way, autolayout will use more memory then calculating frame yourself. As iOS Keyboard extension has a very harsh memory usage limit (around 40mb depends on your device). If your keyboard would use many memory on process other things, I suggest you don't use autolayout.